# User has .NET Framework or not

Tags: .net

Is there any way to find out does user have installed .NET Framework 2.0 or not in browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you browse with Microsoft Internet Explorer 6.0 Beta,

you may receive a user agent string similar to the following:

*User Agent :: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0b; Windows NT 5.1; **.NET CLR 1.0.2914**)*

[Reference 1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306576),
[Reference 2](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheNETFrameworkAndTheBrowsersUserAgentString.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean Javascript? Don't know if thats the case but for codebehind.. You can if you can access the registry files..

[Check it out.](http://geekswithblogs.net/lorint/archive/2006/01/30/67654.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. The browser doesn't provide such information. You may look at the request HTTP headers. Some versions of IE might send this information in the `User-Agent` header but this is not something you may rely on.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to know for sure in all cases, but if the user is using IE, then the user agent string will contain the CLR version(s) installed. e.g.     `Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506`

If they're using Firefox, it might also be possible to tell as the .Net Framework sometimes installs a Firefox extension that adds this to the user-agent string , e.g. `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)`

You can access the user-agent string on a webpage using the Javascript `navigator.userAgent` variable.